Get PID from tc code using struct __sk_buff *skb
The bpf.c code
#include <linux/bpf.h>
#include <linux/pkt_cls.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>
#include "include/ip.h"
#include <linux/tcp.h>
#include <linux/udp.h>
#include "include/helpers.h"
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/net.h>


#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/in.h>

#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <bpf/bpf_endian.h>


#define ETH_P_IP 0x0800 /* Internet Protocol Packet */
#define PROTO_TCP 6
#define PROTO_UDP 17

struct packetdets {
    __u32 source;
    __u16 source_port;
    __u32 dest;
    __u16 dest_port;
    __u8 ip_protocol;
};

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH);
    __type(key, struct packetdets);
    __type(value, __u64);
    __uint(max_entries, 1000);
} pkt_count SEC(".maps");

SEC("tc_prog")
int tc_main(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(__u64)skb->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(__u64)skb->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth;
    struct iphdr *ip;
    struct tcphdr *tcp;
    struct udphdr *udp;
    // if (skb->protocol != bpf_htons(ETH_P_IP))
    //     return TC_ACT_OK;

    eth = data;
    if (data + sizeof(struct ethhdr) > data_end)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    ip = data + 0;
    // ip = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);
    if ((void *)ip + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end)
        return TC_ACT_OK;

    __u32 source = bpf_ntohl(ip->addrs.saddr);
    __u32 dest = bpf_ntohl(ip->addrs.daddr);
    if (dest == 3116855193){
        return TC_ACT_SHOT;
    }

    //extract the port from tcp or ip headers
    __u16 source_port;
    __u16 dest_port;
    __u8 ip_proto;
    if (ip->protocol == PROTO_TCP) {
        tcp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl*4;
        if ((void *)tcp + sizeof(struct tcphdr) > data_end) {
            return TC_ACT_OK;
        }
        source_port = tcp->source;
        dest_port = tcp->dest;
        ip_proto = PROTO_TCP;
    } else if (ip->protocol == PROTO_UDP) {
        udp = (void *)ip + ip->ihl*4;
        if ((void *)udp + sizeof(struct udphdr) > data_end) {
            return TC_ACT_OK;
        }
        source_port = udp->source;
        dest_port = udp->dest;
        ip_proto = PROTO_UDP;
    } else {
        return TC_ACT_OK;
    }



    struct packetdets key = {
        .source = source,
        .source_port = source_port,
        .dest = dest,
        .dest_port = dest_port,
        .ip_protocol = ip_proto,
    };
    __u64 *count = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&pkt_count, &key);
    if (count) {
        __sync_fetch_and_add(count, 1);
    } else {
        __u64 value = 1;
        bpf_map_update_elem(&pkt_count, &key, &value, BPF_ANY);
    }

    char hello_str[] = "hello pkt ipv4: %u";
    bpf_trace_printk(hello_str, sizeof(hello_str), &skb->remote_ip4);
    return TC_ACT_OK;
}

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

Here I'm using a tc/eBPF code. I'm attaching it using these commands:
#!/bin/bash
go generate
go build -o a.out main.go tc_bpfel.go
sudo ./a.out

What I'm trying to do is achieve something like
struct packetdets {
    __u32 source;
    __u16 source_port;
    __u32 dest;
    __u16 dest_port;
    __u8 ip_protocol;
    __u32 pid,
};

int tc_main(struct __sk_buff *skb)
{
int pid = (int)bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    struct packetdets key = {
        .source = source,
        .source_port = source_port,
        .dest = dest,
        .dest_port = dest_port,
        .ip_protocol = ip_proto,
        .pid = pid,    
};


I want to send pid with the structure too. I'm then fetching it from userspace go lang code. I will then use syscall with the fetched pid to terminate some connections. When I run using the mentioned commands:
I get
pegasus@pegasus:~/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc$ ./build-and-run.sh 
/home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/bpf/bpf.c:49:47: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   49 |     int pid = (int)bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
      |                                               ^  ~~
1 warning generated.
Compiled /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfel.o
Stripped /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfel.o
Wrote /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfel.go
/home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/bpf/bpf.c:49:47: warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
   49 |     int pid = (int)bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
      |                                               ^  ~~
1 warning generated.
Compiled /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfeb.o
Stripped /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfeb.o
Wrote /home/pegasus/Documents/cilium-ebpf-tc/tc_bpfeb.go
2024/05/05 05:37:48 loading objects: field TcMain: program tc_main: load program: invalid argument: unknown func bpf_get_current_pid_tgid#14 (10 line(s) omitted)


Please don't tag the C code with C++. The code would raise other errors in C++.

Well, https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html suggests that the bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() returns a u64, which doesn't fit into your int.  That's what's causing the first 2 warnings. As for the last one, I have no idea what that might be about.

Looks like a typo. You might want int pid = (int)(bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32);

You are trying to use the bpf_get_current_pid_tgid helper, but that helper function isn't available for TC programs because they are not executed in a process context but in the network stack.
You also have to keep in mind that when a SKB is for a new packet, its not yet linked to a socket, that happens after TC on the ingress side of things.
The only way I can think of to make the association is to use a secondary program which records socket -> pid association in a map which is shared with your TC program.
I believe the BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK would work. Depending on the attach type it is called whenever a socket is created, released or bound within the cGroup the program is attached to. You can attach the program to the root cGroup (at least with v2 cgroups, not sure about v1) to trigger on all processes on the host.
The cgroup_sock program is allowed to call bpf_get_current_pid_tgid and its context is a pointer to a struct bpf_sock. You should be able to use the pointer as key (perhaps after some conversion) to a hash map with the pid as value. If this map is shared with the TC program, you should be able to use the struct bpf_sock pointer at (struct __sk_buff)->sk to do a lookup in the map.
I have not personally tried this, so no guarantees that this technique works. Would love to hear how others approached this.
